# Using pretrained word2vector model

Tags: nlp, lstm, word2vec

I am trying to use a pretrained word2vector model to create word embeddings but i am getting the following error when Im trying to create weight matrix from word2vec genism model:

Code:

```
import gensim
w2v_model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("/content/drive/My Drive/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz", binary=True)

vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
print(vocab_size)
EMBEDDING_DIM=300
# Function to create weight matrix from word2vec gensim model
def get_weight_matrix(model, vocab):
    # total vocabulary size plus 0 for unknown words
    vocab_size = len(vocab) + 1
    # define weight matrix dimensions with all 0
    weight_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM))
    # step vocab, store vectors using the Tokenizer's integer mapping
    for word, i in vocab.items():
        weight_matrix[i] = model[word]
    return weight_matrix

embedding_vectors = get_weight_matrix(w2v_model, tokenizer.word_index)
```

Im getting the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnCoC.png)

Answer (score 0):

As a note: it's better to paste a full error is as formatted text than as an image of text. (See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for a full list of the reasons why.)

But regarding your question:

If you get a `KeyError: word 'didnt' not in vocabulary` error, you can trust that the word you've requested is not in the set-of-word-vectors you've requested it from. (In this case, the `GoogleNews` vectors that Google trained & released back around 2012.)

You could check before looking it up – `'didnt' in w2v_model`, which would return `False`, and then do something else. Or you could use a Python `try: ... catch: ...` formulation to let it happen, but then do something else when it happens.

But it's up to you what your code should do if the `model` you've provided doesn't have the word-vectors you were hoping for.

(Note: the `GoogleNews` vectors do include a vector for `"didn't"`, the contraction **with** its internal apostrophe. So in this one case, the issue may be that your tokenization is stripping such internal-punctuation-marks from contractions, but Google chose not to when making those vectors. But your code should be ready for handling missing words in any case, unless you're sure through other steps that can never happen.)